# Launcher icon path in app Inventor

Tags: listview, icon, launcher, файловые-пути

В app inventor в listView у меня сделан список названий моих приложений, которые открываются при клике на названии. В список можно добавлять новые элементы. Не знаю, как добавить в каждую строку ещё картинку, которая будет автоматически выбираться из файла apk при добавлении названия в список (позже, после установки) и запоминания его в TinyDb. Это иконка launcher должна быть просто image в listView. Нужно прописать путь к файлу launcher.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)